# Difference between "armistice" and "peace treaty"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What is the difference between ***armistice*** and ***peace treaty***?

Comment: A good dictionary will provide you the answer to questions of this sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armistice):

> An armistice is a **formal agreement of warring parties to stop
>   fighting**. It is **not necessarily the end of a war, since it might
>   be just a cessation of hostilities** while an attempt is made to
>   negotiate a lasting peace. It is derived from the Latin arma, meaning
>   weapons and statium, meaning a stopping.
>
> An armistice is a modus vivendi and is not the same as a peace treaty,
>   **which may take months or even years to agree on**. The 1953 Korean War Armistice Agreement is a major example of an armistice which has
>   not been followed by a peace treaty.

Also, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_treaty):

> A peace treaty is an **agreement between two or more hostile
>   parties**, usually countries or governments, which **formally ends a
>   state of war between the parties**. It is different from an
>   **armistice**, which is an **agreement to stop hostilities**, or a surrender, in which an army agrees to give up arms, or a ceasefire
>   (truce) in which the parties may agree to temporarily or permanently
>   stop fighting.

The difference should be quite clear by now. A peace treaty is a formal arrangement to end war permanently. Armistice is just a temporary cessation of armed conflict.

Usually, an armistice is the first step taken towards a peace treaty.